# How to evaluate which DLL-Files/references are really used at runtime?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a bundle of helper-method packed into an own class library (i.e. Tools.dll). When I start a new project I almost everytime reference this library.
When Visual Studio compiles my new project I get a bunch of files in the bin\debug-folder. Of course there are "mynewproject.exe" and "Tools.dll" but since the helper-methods have own references I also find "HtmlAgilityPack.dll", "Scintilla.dll" etc. wheter I really used some of these functionalities or not.
My question is: Can I get rid of them?
If Visual Studio can filter them out themself, perfekt, if I have to do it manually at runtime, can you offer me an idea how to do that?

I did a lot of research but I can't find a method to analyse which dlls are used or to analyse at runtime which method calls which helper-method.

Thanks a lot!

Update to specify my idea:
My idea was to run a script every time the program is started which checks which dll-files are there and then runs recursive through all methods to look which files are really needed. Then I could delete the unused dll-files. If that script needs to long I could additionally add a flag so this script has only to run once after every compiling.

If anyone has a better idea I'm of course interested :)

Comment: Maybe split up your Tools.dll?

Comment: Instead of referencing your tools assembly, you could link to the source code you use and compile only those files into your main assembly. Or just split your tools into different parts.

Comment: You could run your application under the debgger and look at Debug > Windows > Modules

Comment: @HansKeﬆing: That's not a bad idea. I'm still hoping for a even nicer solution but not a bad idea...

Comment: @JeremyLakeman: Can you explain (or give me a hint) how I can link to a sourcecode without referencing to the whole assembly?

Comment: The depencencies of your dependencies **are your dependencies too**. If `Tools.dll` needs other libraries, these must be included too. If you think they're too much, maybe your original library is doing too much.

Comment: Besides, what's wrong with just ship all the libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool to get this information. In the Runtime Summary window you will see all assemblies, classes and methods used during the program execution. And for each method you will see how it was called.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, it is a little bit pricy for my little private projects.
My idea was to run a script every time the program is started which checks which dll-files are there and then runs recursive through all methods to look which files are really needed. Then I could delete the unused dll-files. If that script needs to long I could additionally add a flag so this script has only to run once after every compiling.

Comment: Could I do something like that with your tool? It looked like it would "only" track the actual ongoing process in an extra windows. Also an interesting feature but not so helpful for me. (sorry for the splitted comment)

Comment: Runtime Flow is designed primarily for external manual exploration. 

Inside the program you can call System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() to see actually used .NET dlls.